# Saving formatted text from textarea to database

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, ckeditor

Is it possible to save formatted text from a textarea? I have embeded my textarea with a ckeditor plugin, and I was wondering if it is possible to save the formatted text(for example, I changed the font size to 9) in the database? Or do I have to change the datatype of my field other than string?

Comment: wouldn't be much point using ckeditor if you couldn't save the formatting

Comment: @marchemike Can I ask you why you asked this question? ps: DB column/field type for handling formatted data should be TEXT :P

Comment: @Joem I'm fairly new to using ckeditor, so I was wondering how would I save the data to the database without removing the format, because I need the formatted text to be outputted to a separate webpage later on. I also have not tried using the TEXT datatype before so I have not thought of what you said.

Comment: So... CMS youre working (formatting) on is removing format? I mean have you tried anything yet? ps: This can be complex answer so Im asking for more info from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CKeditor text area will pass HTML when submitted. That's the formatted text. If you output that, it'll be formatted on the page too.

Answer (score 1):

OK your not here so let me give you more tips as possible.

1. Formatting via CKE end inserting full HTML data in your DB is of course possible (and getting data out as HTML page for example via simple string (like `$formatted_data` for example)). CKE, after submitting your work, is sending full HTML to your database ie(`<a href="http://www.example.com" taget="_blank"><font size=2>I love someone</font></a>`). CKE does full job about that matter. You just do WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) work.
2. Database filed/column which will save/handle that data should be TEXT.

But, depending on your CMS (core quality) structure, installing CKE may be somewhat complex at start. Even from backend it will give you some (security/DB insert) problems probably - and again - depending on your CMS core structure. You will find many answers here if problems occur how to convert characters given/sent by CKE to DB..
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Anyway, after echoing CKE data from DB in ie `article['formatted_article']` fashion youll get full HTML out. Font sizes, tables, rows, images, urls.. everything. And yea, via single string.